# Selecting items with same name and adding each value the line holds

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve data for a line and each line in the table has different unit sold value. I want to sum up the values and distinct the item `descr`.

I used the following code,

```
select distinct s.descr, SUM(s.unitqty)
from saleslines s
```

Comment: You are missing the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the grouping for which you want to apply the sum function:

```
SELECT s.descr, SUM(s.unitqty) AS sum_of_unitqty
FROM saleslines s
GROUP BY s.descr
```

The `distinct` keyword is unnecessary as the `group by` will ensure uniqueness within the groups.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but will this repeat lines with the same description?

Comment: No, it will group items with the same description together and produce a sum for the group so you'll get one row per group.

Comment: Perfect that worked thank you. My other question is, the Table i am working with does NOT have a  date/ time inserted column, is it possible to have a syntax that can pull the data using the script based on system date and time?

Comment: If you don't store the date/time when the data is inserted there is no standard way to retrieve it. There might be a database specific way to get the insert date/time. It's would be better to ask this as a separate question (with some more detail) though.